# TextField action using iText Library

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, textfield

I'm trying to add action for a textfield to a pdf file using iTextSharp lib, but it doesn't worked for me.
This is my code in C#

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("pdf/116700.pdf");
FileStream fs = new FileStream("pdf2/result.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);

TextField note1 = new TextField(stamp.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(499, 428, 420, 416), "note1");
note1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
note1.Text = "0";
PdfFormField ffield = note1.GetTextField();
ffield.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.BL, PdfAction.JavaScript("app.alert('action!')", stamp.Writer));        
stamp.AddAnnotation(note1.GetTextField(), 1);
stamp.Close();
```

Comment: *but it doesn't worked for me* - what do you mean by that? Please state in which pdf viewer you observe which unexpected behavior.

Comment: the action does not fired (the alert not shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a textfield widget annotation

```
PdfFormField ffield = note1.GetTextField();
```

and add the blur action to it

```
ffield.SetAdditionalActions(PdfName.BL, PdfAction.JavaScript("app.alert('action!')", stamp.Writer));
```

and then you create another widget annotation (without blur action) and add only this new annotation to the PDF:

```
stamp.AddAnnotation(note1.GetTextField(), 1);
```

Thus, the annotation with the blur action never is written to the PDF!

---

If you replace that last line by

```
stamp.AddAnnotation(ffield, 1);
```

everything works as expected.